# Solr documents with multiple parents

Tags: solr

I'm currently trying to figure out if Solr is the right tool for me. I have the following setup:

There is the primary document type "blog". Then there are two additional document types "user" and "category". Both of these are parents of the "blog" document type.

Now when searching the "blog" documents, I not only want to search in those fields (e.g. title and content), but also in the parent fields (user>name and category>name.

Of course, I could just flatten that down to a single document for Solr, which would ease the search a lot. The downside to this is though, that when e.g. a user updates their name, I have to run through all blog posts of them and update the documents for that in Solr, instead of just updating a single document.

This becomes even worse when the user has another parent, on which I need to search as well.

Do you have any recommendations about how to handle this use case? Maybe my Google foo is just not good enough, but what I found (block joins, etc.) don't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolutely most performant and *easiest* solution would be to flatten everything to a single document. It turns out that these relations aren't updated as often as people think, and that searches are performed more often than the documents update. And even if one of the values that are identical across a large set of documents change, reindexing from the most recent documents (for a blog) and then going backwards will appear rather performant for most users. The assumes that you have to actually search the values and don't just need the values - which you could look up from secondary storage when displaying an item (and just store the never changing id in the document).

Another option is to divide this into a multi-search problem. One collection for blog posts, one collection for users and one collection for categories. You then search through each of the collections for the relevant data and merge it in your search model. You can also use [Streaming Expressions] to hand off most of this processing to a Solr cluster for you.

The reason why I always recommend flattening if possible is that most features in Solr (and Lucene) are written for a flat document structure, and allows you to fully leverage the features available. Since Lucene by design is a flat document store, most other features require special care to support blockjoins and parent/child relationships, and you end up experimenting a lot to get the correct queries and feature set you want (if possible). If the documents are flat, it just works.

Comment: I totally understand you, but the fact is that there are things in the parents which will just happen to update quite often, which would result in possibly 100 or 1000 of documents needing an update. I don't worry too much about Solr here, but my application side has to do some heavy lifting for that.

Is there maybe an option to tell Solr to update one specific field on all documents which match a certain search criteria? Then I could just tell it to e.g. "update field "name" on all documents which have field "userId" set to 123".

Comment: Performing the update on the Solr side with 1k documents shouldn't take more than a second or two, depending on your structure. If you can't optimize the indexing processing from your application better, then looking at Streaming Expressions might be a possible solution. But really - reindexing a set of documents _should_ always be a performant operation, as you should be able to do it if your datastore and Solr comes out of sync (downtime, broken network connections, etc.).

Comment: Well, re-indexing can be done on the backend without any user interaction, so the waiting-time is not really important there. But when the user is just editing his data, he doesn't want to wait a few seconds or all possible affected documents to be updated.

Comment: You won't be able to do a multi document update (like UPDATE .. WHERE ..), but you could write a middleware that fetches all documents from Solr with the old value and issues updates for all fields. It will still require a bit of time to perform, though - and requires custom code. I'd still go with the "reindex these 1000 documents" unless the content size of those documents are huge. When you're talking about multi-parent relationships you've already ended up in a special case that Lucene doesn't really support.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. I may look into Elasticsearch then, as that one at least has update by query :)